# How can I correct this without errors?

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

```
\[ 
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{\lambda \in \wedge} $x^\lambda_p$}= 1 
\] 
&  \forall $p$ \in \ $P$
```

[image]

Comment: please provide a comple example that shows your issue, `\mathlarger`  is not a standard command. But in general you shoul duse a multi-line math environment such as `align` and then remove all `\[` and `$`

Comment: There are many erroneous `$` characters inside math mode. Please, read a LaTeX manual/documentation/book/... about the difference between text and math mode and how to enter and leave math mode.

Comment: Please supply a minimal working example (MWE, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/113546).
In the meantime some observations: `\[ ... \]` introduces math mode, so inside it you cannot use `$...$`. Just remove the $'s. And the `&` requires some array-like structure around it, but `\[...\]` cannot be inside that. Ans then the $'s there must also be removed because the rest is also math.

Comment: Is there any reason for a double `\mathlarger`? I see not even the need for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be as simple as this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{\lambda \in \wedge} x^\lambda_p = 1 
 \quad \forall p \in  P
\]

\end{document}
```

But do you really want such a big SUM operator?

[image]

Comment: its okay no matter the sum size, thanks a lot i was trying a lot to do it

Comment: thank you it works, spent a lot of time searching how to do it well